# How to prove this set is a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis

- List item

Ex: how to prove the sphere

> $$\left\{ (x,y,z)∈ℝ^3∣x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \right\}$$ is a closed set??

I tried to use the definition of the closed set,but it did not work out for me.

Comment: Which definition of closed set are you using?

Comment: It may be easier to show that the complement is open.

Comment: I tried use the the complements is open,but i cant really show that  X^2+y^2+z^2>1 is open.

Comment: You might also find [Is a sphere a closed set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153655/is-a-sphere-a-closed-set) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hint would be: show that the "inside" is open and the "outside" is open.

To add a bit more details: Let $\tilde{x}$ denote an arbitrary point in $\mathrm{Outside}=\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2 + y^2+z^2 > 1\}.$ Thinking about it geometrically, the ball centered at $\tilde{x}$ of radius $|\tilde{x}| -1$ should be a subset of $\mathrm{Outside}$. So, you should try showing this.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint*: Use the fact that inverse images of closed sets through continuous functions are closed.