# Is the set $C = \{(x, y, z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \pi\}$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am working on a problem in which I must determine if the extrema (I found these in the initial part of the problem) of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$, constrained to the set

$$C = \{(x, y, z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \pi\},$$

are global extrema.
NB: $C$ is the sphere of radius $\sqrt\pi$, centred at the origin.

I know that if $C$ is compact (both closed and bounded), then the extrema of $f$ constrained to $C$ (found in the initial part of the problem) will be global extrema.

I think that $C$ is bounded, but am not sure if my understanding of a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is correct, especially after having read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153655/is-a-sphere-a-closed-set).

Also, I am not sure how to determine if $C$ is closed.
The definition of a closed set is one whose complement is open (or a set which contains all its limit points).
I am not sure if the complement of $C$ is open, seeing as some points in the complement of $C$ lie within the sphere and others lie outside the sphere.

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: $C$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb R^3$, therefore it's compact.

Comment: Open doesn't mean connected. There's nothing wrong with the complement having two disjoint pieces. Each piece is an open set and a union of open sets is open. Also, bounded doesn't mean that it has a boundary. It means that you can fit it inside a ball of some radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y2+z^2$ is continuous therefore $g^{-1}(\pi)=C$ is closed

$C$ is not empty $(\sqrt{\pi},0,0)$

$\forall (x,y,z)\in C, |x| = \sqrt{\pi-y^2-z^2} \le \sqrt{\pi},|y| = \sqrt{\pi-x^2-z^2} \le \sqrt{\pi},|z| = \sqrt{\pi-y^2-x^2} \le \sqrt{\pi}$

So $C$ is bounded

Therefore C is compact

Comment: Please could you explain why, if $g$ is continuous, then the pre-image $g^{-1}$ is closed?  Also, could you please explain why the three inequalities show that $C$ is bounded?

Comment: $\{\pi\}$ is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ and the pre-image of a closed set by a continuous function is closed

Comment: @CKKOY Bounded means that the norm of all the elements in the set is majored. Here, as you said, it's the sphere of radius $\sqrt{\pi}$ so $$\forall (x,y,z) \in C, ||(x,y,z)||_2 = \sqrt{\pi}$$ and what i've shown is that $$||(x,y,z)||_{\infty}=\max_{(x,y,z) \in C} ({|x|,|y|,|z|}) = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: Firstly, what does it mean to say that 'the norm of all the elements in the set is majored'?  Secondly, what does the notation $||(x, y, z)||_2$ and the notation $||(x, y, z)||_{\infty}$ mean, please?

Comment: @CKKOY It means : $\exists M > 0 / \forall (x,y,z)\in C, ||(x,y,z)|| \le M$

Comment: $||(x,y,z)||_2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $||(x,y,z)||_{\infty} = \max(|x|,|y|,|z|)$ they are both  norms on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you can take whatever norm you want because they are equivalent