# Show a sphere are closed sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space, then a subset $H \subset X$ is defined as a closed set of $X$ if $X-H$ is open in $X$.

> Let $B$ be a sphere with north pole removed. Is B a closed set or an open set of $\mathbb E^3$ (3-dimensional euclidean space).

Comment: What does the space $R^3$ consist of if you remove a sphere?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153655/is-a-sphere-a-closed-set?rq=1

Comment: Um, this is not what the original question was.

Comment: The way the new question is phrased, it's a trick question because the answer is that it is neither a closed set nor an open set.

Comment: in am learning about "topological bases and generated topologies" from my lecture note i want to know "how to show that a sphere $S$ with radius $r \gt 0$ or a plane are closed sets of $\mathbb E^3$, then new question arises "if $A$ be a sphere with north pole removed, is A a closed set or an open set of $\mathbb E^3$ ?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{E}^3$?

Comment: $\mathbb E^3$ is the 3-dimensional euclidean space

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a point not in the sphere. Suppose the distance of $x$ from the origin is $d$. Then all of the points in the open ball of radius $\frac{|d-r|}2$ centered at $x$ lie outside the sphere. Since the open balls form a basis for the topology and every point in the complement has an open ball around it that is entirely contained in the complement, the complement of a sphere is open, hence the sphere is closed.

Obviously I glossed over why this open ball does not intersect the sphere. This is because it requires some calculation and I'm answering this on a cell phone. I think you should be able to figure that part out.

Edit: The question has been edited to make this answer invalid. I am not going to modify it to have it answer the new, completely different question.

Comment: can you explain "it requires some calculation", it is still not clear for me. Thank you

Comment: @user You can bound the distance from the sphere from below.